# Problem with Finding Controls of a page that uses a Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a set of pages, each page is used to prompt the user for data and create a record for this data in the database.

I use the same technique for all the pages .. 2 panels, the first has all the input controls and is visible by default and a second panel that shows a success message and is hidden by default.

Now when the user clicks the "Submit" button .. if the data is valid, I write a couple of lines to hide the first panel and show the first one .. I have like 20 pages that uses the same technique so as a good practice I added a class to my web project that's called Helper that searches for the 2 panels, then hide and show what I need.

I used the same panel Id for all the pages so I could use it easily!

N.B: I first just went ahead and searched for the panel directly but it won't work so I tried to search for the content control that holds the panels and stuff (as this page is using a master page) and then find the Panel. both attempts won't work out!

```
public class Helpers
{
    public static void SuccessfulSubmission(Page p)
    {
        Content content = p.FindControl("Content2") as Content;
        Panel inputPanel = content.FindControl("inputPanel") as Panel;
        inputPanel.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where the inputPanel is located ? on the page, or on master page ? and where are you calling the SuccessfulSubmission, from the master or from the page ?

Comment: @Aristos .. The InputPanel is located in the Content control of the Page. And I call "SuccessfulSubmission" from the OnClick_even of the "Submit" button that exists in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching content control would never work because whenever master page is used, its controls get inserted into the page and page's controls (within content control) gets added to the corresponding content placeholders. Perhaps, you should try to locate the content placeholders first and then try finding the control.

However, a better design would be creating a base page class along with specific master page to control this interaction. For example,

You will have a master page (say named as TwoPanelMaster)that would use your site master page and use two panel layout along with submit button. Idea is you have standard layout that is controlled via master page.

```
  <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="InputPanel">
     <asp:ContentPlaceholder runat="server" ID="Input"></asp:ContentPlaceholder>
  </asp:Panel>
  <asp:Panel runat="Server" ID="Message">
     <!-- put the UI for displaying message -->
  </asp:Panel>
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Submit" />
```

Expose methods in the master code behind to get access to submit button, to show/hide panels etc.

Now create a base page class that would code the basic interaction -

```
public abstract class InputPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected override OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  {
     var master = this.Master as TwoPanelMaster;
     master.GetSubmitButton().OnClick += Submit_Click();
  }

  private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     ValidateInput();
  }

  protected virtual void ValidateInput()
  {
     // do some common code (if any)
     string message;
     if (OnValidateInput(out message))
     {
        // validation succesful, show success message
        var master = this.Master as TwoPanelMaster;
        master.ShowMessage(message); // this method should hide the input panel and display message panel.
     }
  }

  // pages should provide implementation of this method
  protected abstract bool OnValidateInput(out string successMessage);

}
```

This is a general approach that would give you a more control and remove dependency such that your pages must have panels having particular ID etc.

Comment: . Thanks for suggesting a better design +1. I needed a better design not just a simple solution to get by the day .. But I didn't quite understand the approach specially the last part (base page class) .. What I got the dependency removal by making the panel itself a template (in the master page) and having the submit button function defined in the master page so I don't have to define it or search for it in the pages that's using the master page .. But still what is a "Base Page Class" ? .. Thanks for your time and sorry for the late reply =)

Comment: @IKashef, a base page is created to capture common work-flow/logic- e.g. here, a common logic is - validate input, if successful show message panel & hide input panel. So this logic would be captured in base class while page specific logic such as validating actual stuff will be delegated to the page it self via abstract method. Your actuals pages should inherit from this bas page class rather than `System.Web.UI.Page`. Base page is  encapsulating all interactions with master page class-in the absence of it, all pages would have this interaction resulting in more work for any future change.

Comment: . That's a lot to take! but thank you anyway for your help. It looks like a good solution but I'll have to do a little research and read it more than once to get a grasp of this method .. I'll comment to let you know if I needed further help =)